# Once a package is deployed, are the components immediately visible?

Tags: deployment, unmanaged-package

I created a VF page, packed it and deployed to a staging org. I am not able to see my VF page in the staging org. Is this supposed to be this way or I should usually be able to see it immediately? I could see my package in my Package Manager, but I it is not installed, so I suppose I should install it now in order to see the page

Comment: Once successfully installed, all components are immediately available. Are you sure you saw "Installation successful"? Sometimes, you'll get a message that installation will occur asynchronously and you'll be notified by email when it completes. Once it completes, the page will be there.

Comment: I used the CLI to deploy. After the deploy command I received a Status: Successful. I am not sure if this necessary means that it was installed or just deployed. If so, I am not sure how to install now. If not, then there must be something wrong

Comment: No, it's all in real time. Once you see success, it's available. Did you make sure it's in your package.xml? Any errors or warnings? There's a lot of things that can go wrong with the CLI if you're not used to using it.

Comment: This is a screenshot of the CLI: https://imgur.com/a/pubcv
It shows that the unpackages.zip was deployed, which contained my package.xml. In regard to errors, however, I noticed that when in the Package Manager, I click on the package name itself, I see something like:

Bad References Found
Please press Recompile All or edit and resave the following items

Screenshot:
https://imgur.com/a/0ofEX

Answer (score 0):

The pieces are there. The community needs to be activated or deployed or published or whatever it's called.